# Get length of jstring/char *?

Tags: java, c++, c, java-native-interface

This is my JNI C code:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_avuna_httpd_util_CLibJNI_bind(JNIEnv * this, jclass cls, jint sockfd, jint family, jstring path, jint len) {
    struct sockaddr_un sun;
    sun.sun_family = family;
    const char *npath = (*this)->GetStringUTFChars(this, path, 0);
    sun.sun_path = npath;
    return bind(sockfd, sun, sizeof(&npath));
}
```

I just guessed unsuccessfully (`sizeof(&npath)`) how to get the length. I'm not well versed in C, but I figure there is a way to get a length out of a jstring.

Google yields nothing, what basic thing am I missing?

Comment: No, `sizeof()` will not give it the length of the string but the size of the type, are you sure of `(*this)->`?

Comment: @iharob I found it online, testing will show whether it's good or not.

Comment: You can check how `JNIEnv` is defined and whether it's a pointer `typedef` which would mean that `(*this)` makes sense.

Comment: `JNIEnv` is indeed a pointer: `typedef const struct JNINativeInterface *JNIEnv;` thus the JNI functions effectively take a `JNINativeInterface**` as input, so `(*this)->` is correct syntax to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the type of the variable is `const char *` it suggests that it's a `nul` terminated string, hence

```
size_t length = strlen(npath);
```

should be enough.

Although, your call to `bind()` is wrong, you shold pass the size of the address structure, for which

```
return bind(sockfd, sun, sizeof(sun));
```

should be correct.

Comment: The second parameter of `bind()` expects a `sockaddr*` pointer as input: `bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&sun, sizeof(sun))`

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the length of the jstring, what is needed is GetStringUTFLength.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

This should be more efficient than calling strlen on the null terminated char* as I don't think it will need to search for the final null.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a memory leak.  The `char*` pointer returned by `GetStringUTFChars()` *must* be freed using `ReleaseStringUTFChars()`, which you are not doing.

Second, `bind()` expects you to specify the byte size of the `sockaddr_un` struct, not the character length of `npath`.  Also, the second parameter of `bind()` expects a `sockaddr*` pointer as input.

Third, `sockaddr_un::sun_path` is a `char[]` array, you cannot assign a `char*` pointer to it. You have to copy the content that is being pointed at.

Try this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_avuna_httpd_util_CLibJNI_bind(JNIEnv * this, jclass cls, jint sockfd, jint family, jstring path, jint len)
{
    struct sockaddr_un sun;
    memset(&sun, 0, sizeof(sun));
    sun.sun_family = family;
    const char *npath = (*this)->GetStringUTFChars(this, path, 0);
    strncpy(sun.sun_path, npath, UNIX_PATH_MAX);
    (*this)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(this, path, npath);
    return bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sun, sizeof(sun));
}
```

With that said, `sockaddr_un` *always* uses `AF_UNIX` for its family, so it does not make sense to pass a `family` as an input value.  If you need to pass in different `family` values, you need to use a different `sockaddr_...` struct for each `family`, eg:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_avuna_httpd_util_CLibJNI_bind(JNIEnv * this, jclass cls, jint sockfd, jint family, jstring path, jint len)
{
    switch (family)
    {
        case AF_UNIX:
        {
            struct sockaddr_un sun;
            memset(&sun, 0, sizeof(sun));
            sun.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
            const char *npath = (*this)->GetStringUTFChars(this, path, 0);
            strncpy(sun.sun_path, npath, UNIX_PATH_MAX);
            (*this)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(this, path, npath);
            return bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sun, sizeof(sun));
        }

        case AF_INET:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in sin;
            memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
            sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
            const char *npath = (*this)->GetStringUTFChars(this, path, 0);
            inet_pton(AF_INET, npath, &sin.sin_addr);
            sin.sin_port = 0;
            (*this)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(this, path, npath);
            return bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));
        }

        case AF_INET6:
        {
            struct sockaddr_in6 sin;
            memset(&sin, 0, sizeof(sin));
            sin.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
            const char *npath = (*this)->GetStringUTFChars(this, path, 0);
            inet_pton(AF_INET6, npath, &sin.sin6_addr);
            sin.sin6_port = 0;
            (*this)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(this, path, npath);
            return bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof(sin));
        }

        // and so on ...
    }

    return -1;
}
```